# Popular Clientdataset em tempo de execução para executar uma consulta SQL ? Delphi

Tags: delphi

Preciso configurar o CDS para guardar o resultado da consulta, mas sem arrastar os componentes, já que neste caso não estou usando nenhum form, mas me retorna erro 'Invalid Field Type' nos campos informados.
Segue meu código:

```
begin
  CDSEstoque  := TClientDataSet.Create(Application);
  SDSEstoque.Close;
  CDSEstoque.Close;

  CDSEstoque.FieldDefs.Clear;
  CDSEstoque.FieldDefs.add('ID_PRODUTO', ftInteger);
  CDSEstoque.FieldDefs.add('NOME_PRODUTO', ftString, 50);
  CDSEstoque.FieldDefs.add('NCM', ftString, 8);
  CDSEstoque.FieldDefs.add('QTDADE', ftCurrency);
  CDSEstoque.FieldDefs.add('CUSTO_TOTAL', ftCurrency);
  CDSEstoque.FieldDefs.add('CUSTO_UNI', ftCurrency);
  CDSEstoque.FieldDefs.add('UND', ftString, 2);
  CDSEstoque.CreateDataSet;

  DataEstoque := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', pDataFim);

  SDSEstoque.SQLConnection := TDBExpress.getConexao;
  SDSEstoque.CommandText   := 'SELECT M.ID_PRODUTO, A.NOME_PRODUTO, A.NCM, SUM(M.QUANTIDADE) AS QTDADE, ' +
  'SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) AS CUSTO_TOTAL, '+
  '(SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) / SUM(M.QUANTIDADE)) AS CUSTO_UNI, B.SIGLA AS UND '+
  'FROM movimento_produto M '+
  'INNER JOIN produto A ON (A.ID = M.ID_PRODUTO) '+
  'INNER JOIN unidade_produto B ON (B.ID = A.ID_UNIDADE) '+
  'WHERE (M.DATA_MOVIMENTO <= '+QuotedStr(DataEstoque)+') '+
  'AND QTDADE > 0 GROUP BY M.ID_PRODUTO ORDER BY A.NOME_PRODUTO;';

  CDSEstoque.Open;
  SDSEstoque.Open;
end;
```

Comment: não poderia ser o campo de quantidade que está declarado como currency no clientdataset? `CDSEstoque.FieldDefs.add('QTDADE', ftCurrency);` , geralmente campos de qtde. são integer

Comment: mas a quantidade pode ser quebrado, por exemplo 1,5 1,7

Comment: E outra dúvida seria, se estou criando o CDS corretamente

Comment: O que é "SDSEstoque"? E onde está sendo relacionado o CDS com um DataSetProvider?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi alterando o CDSEstoque, de TClientDataSet para TSQLQuery, e o código ficou assim:

```
procedure PopulaCDSBlocoH(pDataFim: TDate);
var
   SQL, DataEstoque: String;
   cdsTemp:           TClientDataSet;
begin
   CDSEstoque  := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
   DataEstoque := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', pDataFim);

   SQL         :=  'SELECT M.ID_PRODUTO, A.NOME_PRODUTO, A.NCM, SUM(M.QUANTIDADE) AS QTDADE, ' +
   'SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) AS CUSTO_TOTAL, '+
   '(SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) / SUM(M.QUANTIDADE)) AS CUSTO_UNI, B.SIGLA AS UND '+
   'FROM movimento_produto M '+
   'INNER JOIN produto A ON (A.ID = M.ID_PRODUTO) '+
   'INNER JOIN unidade_produto B ON (B.ID = A.ID_UNIDADE) '+
   'WHERE (M.DATA_MOVIMENTO <= '+QuotedStr(DataEstoque)+') '+
   'AND M.QUANTIDADE > 0 GROUP BY M.ID_PRODUTO ORDER BY A.NOME_PRODUTO';

   CDSEstoque.SQLConnection := TDBExpress.getConexao;
   CDSEstoque.SQL.Text      := SQL;
   CDSEstoque.Open;
   CDSEstoque.First;

end;
```